# php shuffle() returns one item

Tags: php

Anyone have any idea why shuffle() would only return 1 item?

when using:

```
$array2 = shuffle($array1);
```

with the following array($array1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 14
)
```

The output of:

```
print_r($array2);
```

is simply: **1**

Any idea as to why it would not only not shuffle the array, but knock off the remaining 9 items in the array?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shuffle()` shuffles the array in place, and returns true if it succeeded. If you want `$array2` to be a shuffled version of `$array1`, first make it a copy of `$array1` and then call `shuffle($array2);`

See the docs: [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle)

Comment: So whats the point of shuffling it if its going to just return true/false?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. It shuffles *in place*. If you printed out `$array1` instead of `$array2` in your code you would have gotten a shuffled version.

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand. Makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a function that shuffles and returns a shuffled copy of the array?

Answer (score 2):

shuffle changes the original array. So in your case the shuffled array is `$array1`.

`$array2` is simply a boolean value. The function returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Please read a function description before use http://php.net/shuffle
it may work other than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array2 = $array1;
shuffle($array2);
print_r($array2);
```